# How to remove spaces between words in R?

Tags: r

I have been trying to eliminate or substitute the sapace between words leaving the other spaces untouched. An example is:

`string <- "Hi buddy        3.256.225    25.365.425"`

and want it to be:

`string <- "Hibuddy        3.256.225    25.365.425"`

I have been trying to use "gsub" and "str" but all spaces get eliminated and just want to remove the ones between words.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may capture the letter without the space and use the backreference (`\\1`, `\\2`) in `gsub`

```
gsub("([A-Za-z])\\s+([A-Za-z])", "\\1\\2", string)
[1] "Hibuddy 3.256.225 25.365.425"
```

The above regex matches any letter (`[A-Za-z]`) capture as a group (`(...)`), followed by one or more spaces (`\\s+`) and another letter, which is captured as a group as well.  In the replacement, specify the backreferences of those captured groups without any spaces

Comment: Hi, It almost worked, the thing is I have some rows with "Hi Buddy how are you 42,5285" and now I got "HiBuddyhow areyou 42,5285" have one extra space there.

Comment: @EduardoOrellanaBuigley I am not getting that space though.  Do you have any utf-8 encoded characters i..e `str2 <- "Hi Buddy how are you 42,5285";
gsub("([A-Za-z])\\s+([A-Za-z])", "\\1\\2", str2)#
[1] "HiBuddyhowareyou 42,5285"`

Comment: @EduardoOrellanaBuigley if there are some special characters.  May be you can do `gsub("([^0-9.])\\s+([^0-9.])", "\\1\\2", str2)#
[1] "HiBuddyhowareyou 42,5285"`

Comment: Hi, thanks, I just fix it, just ran the code twice and worked as a charm.

Comment: @EduardoOrellanaBuigley Glad to know that it works.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `str_squish` from `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
str_squish(string)
```

[1] "Hi buddy 3.256.225 25.365.425"

Comment: you could probably use `str_remove_all(string, "(?<=[A-Za-z])\\s+(?=[A-Za-z])")#
[1] "Hibuddy 3.256.225 25.365.425"` as `str_squish` only removes the whitespace from the beginning and end (if i am not wrong)

Comment: From the help: `str_trim()` removes whitespace from start and end of string; `str_squish()` also reduces repeated whitespace inside a string.