# Extract a vector from nested lists in R

Tags: r

I am trying to extract a vector from a nested list based on the value of another variable\element within the same nested list. Hopefully my example will explain what I'm trying to do.

To begin, I have a list of lists like so:

```
## Create the inner lists
# Inner list 1
listInner1 <- list(
  value = c(0.25),
  index = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  left  = c(),
  right = c()
)

listInner1$left$index  <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
listInner1$left$good   <- TRUE
listInner1$right$index <- c(6, 7, 8, 8, 10)
listInner1$right$good  <- TRUE

# Inner list 2
listInner2 <- list(
  value = c(1.5),
  index = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  left  = c(),
  right = c()
)

listInner2$left$index  <- c(1, 2, 3)
listInner2$left$good   <- TRUE
listInner2$right$index <- c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
listInner2$right$good  <- TRUE

# Inner list 3
listInner3 <- list(
  value = c(0.5),
  index = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  left  = c(),
  right = c()
)

listInner3$left$index  <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
listInner3$right$index <- c( 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
listInner3$left$left$index  <- c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
listInner3$left$right$index <- c(1, 3, 5 ,7, 9)
listInner3$left$left$good <- TRUE
listInner3$left$right$good <- TRUE


# put all inner lists into single list object
listMiddle <- list(listInner1, listInner2, listInner3)

# one more list for fun
listMaster <- list(listMiddle)
```

As you can see, some of the `left` and `right` elements of the nested lists contain the element `good = TRUE` and some don't.

What I'm trying to do is if a particular nested list contains the element `good = TRUE` then to extract the element `index` from that same nested list.

For example, manually creating my desired output for the above example would look something like this:

```
ans <- list(
  index.1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  index.2 = c(6, 7, 8, 8, 10),
  index.3 = c(1, 2, 3),
  index.4 = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  index.5 = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10),
  index.6 = c(1, 3, 5 ,7, 9)
)
```

The object `ans` contains all the `index` vectors that are contained within a nested list that also contains `good = TRUE`.

Any suggestions as to how I could do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option where we `bind` the nested elements to a more easily approachable format with `rrapply`, then, we get the index of 'good' columns, extract the corresponding 'index' elements from that position index by looping over in `map2` (based on the the `TRUE` values), `transpose` the `list` , `keep` only the elements having greater than 0 `length`, `flatten` the `list` and set the names (if needed)

```
library(purrr)
library(rrapply)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
out <- rrapply(listMaster, how = 'bind')
i1 <- grep('good', names(out))
map2(out[i1-1], out[i1], `[`) %>%
   transpose %>%
   map( ~ keep(.x, lengths(.x) > 0)) %>%
   flatten %>%
   setNames(str_c('index.', seq_along(.)))
```

-output

```
$index.1
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$index.2
[1]  6  7  8  8 10

$index.3
[1] 1 2 3

$index.4
[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$index.5
[1]  2  4  6  8 10

$index.6
[1] 1 3 5 7 9
```

Comment: Very complex issue. How you get all this in your brain? :-)

Comment: @TarJae  I think it looks complex only based on my function.  Probably, it may be done more easily i.e. within `rrapply` itself.  I haven't tried much within that, but I am hopeful that it is more easier

Comment: It works perfectly. I was trying for hours and couldn't wrap my head around it. Thanks

Comment: @TarJae please don't believe that I did this in a single stretch.  No, I did not.  It is just that when I try something, I do try on several ways i.e. finding if there are any loopholes within the function.  Some of them may not be there in the documentation.  Some I discover by trial and error.  I think the best way to learn is to try something and when you find an error, you learn something very unique about that function

Comment: @akrun, Glad to hear. So I am not wrong by doing it this way! Although it is very time consuming finally you are right! And master please see here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69093216/how-to-remove-spaces-between-words-in-r/69094325#69094325> What do you think about this answer?